# Button with a certain built-in function makes error

Tags: front-end, dynamic, warning-messages, notebooks, system

Note that if I execute

```
NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], 
 SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "C:\\myfile.nb"]]
```

will popup `Save as..` window whose initial full path is `C:\\myfile.nb`

If I execute

```
Button["Click Here", 
 NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], 
  SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "C:\\myfile.nb"]]]
```

then it generates `Click Here` button. If I press that button, I get an error message :

```
SystemDialogInput::nprmtv: SystemDialogInput is not currently supported within preemptive evaluations.
```

Then how do I create something(?) such that if I activate(?) that something,
it pops up `Save as..` window whose initial full path is `C:\\myfile.nb`.

The solution doesn't have to be a `button`, but it should be easy to activate.
This question can be understood as a problem of bypassing something.

Comment: I don't know the principle, but I found it out through search. Add `Method -> "Queued"` as `Button` Option.

Comment: `Button["Click Here", 
 NotebookSave[InputNotebook[], 
  SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "C:\\myfile.nb"]], Method -> "Queued"]`